# Dell inspiron 15R keyboard not working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dell-inspiron

keys of my **dell inspiron 15R** laptop are not working correctly.

Some of the keys are not at all responding, where as some of them are working but responding incorrectly.

For example if I press **1**, **s** will be typed. when i type **s**, **enter** will type.

I tried to re install the OS, still the problem exists.

Onscreen keyboard works correctly.

Are the problem with keyboard? or virus?

Comment: have you checked to see what keyboard layout you are using? sounds like your computer thinks you're using something other than QWERTY layout. also what OS are you using?

Comment: [Its QWERTY](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=dell+inspiron+15R+keyboard&um=1&hl=en&sa=X&biw=1024&bih=679&tbm=isch&tbnid=GpBdhq7pjCpk1M:&imgrefurl=http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/notebooks/dell/inspiron_15r_n5010/349068&docid=Uq7Az62MHYgjZM&imgurl=http://demo.idg.com.au/images/pcw/Dell_Inspiron_15R_N5010_palm_rest.jpg&w=420&h=280&ei=oM0QUMq9JcTWrQedoIG4Dg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=103&vpy=163&dur=5601&hovh=183&hovw=275&tx=174&ty=101&sig=114337388584855420232&page=1&tbnh=151&tbnw=201&start=0&ndsp=12&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:72) win 7 OS

Comment: does your onscreen keyboard match your physical keyboard exactly?

Comment: What happens if you use an external keyboard?

Comment: On screen keyboard works correctly

Comment: I have not tried external keyboard..

Comment: First it was not working, I reinstaled the OS. Now external keyboard is working... Still other one not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced keyboard itself. now the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the keyboard connection.  It could be slightly offset and reading the input incorrectly. Also, try starting in Safe Mode and see if the problem continues.  That will eliminate software as an issue.